# javascript: How to make a directory in filetree-like structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have code listed below. All "Tree" class works fine. I need help with "makekDir" function (in Node class), it should create new children tree (directory). This code in "makekDir" function `this.findNode(filepath)` always return null. I can't find how to fix it. Can any one help, or give advice how to fix it p.s. sorry for the big chunk of code, don't know would it be understandable if I post only Node class

```
import path from 'path';

//this class works fine
class Tree {
  constructor(key, meta, parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.key = key;
    this.meta = meta;
    this.children = new Map();
  }

  getKey() {
    return this.key;
  }

  getMeta() {
    return this.meta;
  }

  addChild(key, meta) {
    const child = new Tree(key, meta, this);
    this.children.set(key, child);

    return child;
  }

  getChild(key) {
    return this.children.get(key);
  }

  hasChild(key) {
    return this.children.has(key);
  }

  getDeepChild(dirs = []) {
    if (dirs.length === 0 || !Array.isArray(dirs)) {
      console.log('not array');
      return null;
    }
    const [first, ...rest] = dirs;
    console.log(first, ...rest);
    console.log (this);
    if (this.hasChild(first)) {
      return rest.length === 0 
        ? this.getChild(first)
        : this.getChild(first).getDeepChild(rest); 
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class Node {
  constructor() {
    this.tree = new Tree('/', { type: 'dir' });
  }

  ///// I need help with this function
  makekDir(filepath) {
    const { dir } = path.parse(filepath);
    const subtree = this.findNode(filepath);
    return subtree.addChild(dir, { type: 'dir' });
  }
 ///// 

  findNode(filepath) {
    const parts = filepath.split(path.sep).filter((item) => item !== '');
    return parts.length === 0 ? this.tree : this.tree.getDeepChild(parts);
  }
}

console.log(new Node().makekDir('/etc'));
```

Comment: You are not accounting for the possibility that `this.tree.getDeepChild(parts)` can return `null`, which leads you to call `subtree.addChild` on that null value.

Comment: It always returns `null` b/c `(new Tree('/', { type: 'dir' })).getDeepChild(['etc'])` always returns `null`. That's how you've programmed It.

Comment: hmm, you right. "getDeepChild" return ```null``` when tree is empty. it should return deepest existing child ```(new Tree('/', { type: 'dir' })).getDeepChild(['etc', 'vars', 'test'])``` should return "test" for tree like ```/etc/vars/test/```  Have no idea how to fix it. But I will try. ty.